# NP optimization problems (definition)

Tags: algorithm, computability

I'm trying to understand the definition of NPO.

I read the definition here : http://www.nada.kth.se/~viggo/wwwcompendium/node2.html

If we consider trying to find a minimal vertice cover, what is I,sol(x) and m ? (goal is min)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the link you posted I think this is the interpretation for [minimal vertex cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover):

- *I*: The set of all graphs.
- *sol(x)*: The set of possible solutions to a graph **x ∈ I**, that is all subsets of vertices that cover all edges.
- *m(x,y)*: The value of solution *y* to instance *x*. In the vertex cover case the number of vertices in the set.